# Stop Bullet number to be updated automatically when merging word docs using docx4j

Tags: java, merge, docx, docx4j

I am trying to merge 2 docx files which has their own bullet number, after merging of word docs the bullets are automatically updated.

E.g:
Doc A has 1 2 3
Doc B has 1 2 3
After merging the bullet numbering are updated to be 1 2 3 4 5 6
how to stop this.

I am using following code

```
              if(counter==1)
                  { 
                    FirstFileByteStream = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(strFileData.getBytes());
                    FirstFileIS = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(FirstFileByteStream);
                    FirstWordFile = org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(FirstFileIS);
                    main = FirstWordFile.getMainDocumentPart();
                    
                    //Add page break for Table of Content
                    main.addObject(objBr);
                    
                    if (htmlCode != null) {
                    main.addAltChunk(org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.AltChunkType.Html,htmlCode.toString().getBytes());
                    }
                    //Table of contents - End
                  }
                else
                  {
                      
                    FileByteStream = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(strFileData.getBytes());
                    FileIS = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(FileByteStream);                        
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(FileIS);
                    
                    AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/part" + (chunkCount++) + ".docx"));
                    afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType(CONTENT_TYPE));
                    afiPart.setBinaryData(bytes);
                    Relationship altChunkRel = main.addTargetPart(afiPart);
                    CTAltChunk chunk = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
                    chunk.setId(altChunkRel.getId());
                    
                    main.addObject(objBr);
                    
                    htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
                    htmlCode.append("<html>");
                    htmlCode.append("<h2><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><p style=\"font-family:'Arial Black'; color: #f35b1c\">"+ReqName+"</p></h2>");
                    htmlCode.append("</html>");

                    if (htmlCode != null) {
                        main.addAltChunk(org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.AltChunkType.Html,htmlCode.toString().getBytes());
                    }
                    
                    //Add Page Break before new content
                    main.addObject(objBr);
                    
                    //Add new content
                    main.addObject(chunk);
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you are adding HTML altChunks to your document.

For these to display it Word, the HTML is converted to normal docx content.

An altChunk is usually converted by Word when you open the docx.

(Alternatively, docx4j-ImportXHTML can do it for an altChunk of type XHTML)

The upshot is that what happens with the bullets (when Word converts your HTML) is largely outside your control.  You could experiment with CSS but I think Word will mostly ignore it.

An alternative may be to use XHTML altChunks, and have docx4j-ImportXHTML convert them.  `main.convertAltChunks()`

If the same problem occurs when you try that, well, at least we can address it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Is it possible to give an example of how to use main.convertAltChunks(). 
or please provide a link where I can find proper usage of this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue using following code. I found it at (http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/forms/upload_MergeDocx.xhtml). You can also generate your custom code, they have a nice demo where they generate code according to your requirement :).

```
public final static String DIR_IN = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/"; 
public final static String DIR_OUT = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/"; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{ 
    String[] files = {"part1docx_20200717t173750539gmt.docx", "part1docx_20200717t173750539gmt (1).docx", "part1docx_20200717t173750539gmt.docx"}; 
    List blockRanges = new ArrayList(); 
    for (int i=0 ; i< files.length; i++) { 
        BlockRange block = new BlockRange(WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(DIR_IN + files[i]))); 
        blockRanges.add( block ); 
        block.setStyleHandler(StyleHandler.RENAME_RETAIN);
        block.setNumberingHandler(NumberingHandler.ADD_NEW_LIST);
        block.setRestartPageNumbering(false);
        block.setHeaderBehaviour(HfBehaviour.DEFAULT);
        block.setFooterBehaviour(HfBehaviour.DEFAULT);
        block.setSectionBreakBefore(SectionBreakBefore.NEXT_PAGE);
    } 
    // Perform the actual merge 
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(); 
    WordprocessingMLPackage output = documentBuilder.buildOpenDocument(blockRanges); 
    // Save the result 
    SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(output); 
    saver.save(DIR_OUT+"OUT_MergeWholeDocumentsUsingBlockRange.docx"); 
}
```